# Interpreting complex typedef with pointers

Tags: c++, typedef

I have encountered the following `typedef` in a simple C++ application.

```
typedef char *(*TEXT_FUNCTION)();
```

I am relatively new to C++ and need some help understanding what this does. Later in the code, `TEXT_FUNCTION` is referred to in the statement

```
TEXT_FUNCTION textfunction = reinterpret_cast<TEXT_FUNCTION>(
    GetProcAddress(myDLLHandle, "getName")
);
```

Looking at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) for `GetProcAddress()`, I understand that the statement returns the address of the `getName()` function in the DLL referenced by `myDLLHandle`. I assume that the entire cast statement assigns some sort of pointer to the `getName()` function to `textfunction`.

Is this accurate? What do each of the parts of the `typedef` statement mean?

Comment: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) can be useful for deciphering complex `typedef`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type declaration should be read in reverse order of usual evaluation of expression.

usual evaluation of expression will be like

```
* // 4. dereference 3
  (
    * // 2. dereference 1
      TEXT_FUNCTION // 1. read what is in TEXT_FUNCTION
  )
  (); // 3. call function 2
```

So, the type declaration

```
char *(*TEXT_FUNCTION)();
```

means

```
char // 1. char
  * // 2. a pointer to 1
    (
      * // 4. a pointer to 3
        TEXT_FUNCTION // 5. TEXT_FUNCTION is 4
    )
  (); // 3. a function that takes 0 arguments and returns 2
```

Therefore, the `typedef` statement means that declare `TEXT_FUNCTION` as a pointer to a function that takes 0 arguments and returns a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef char *(*TEXT_FUNCTION)();` defines a function pointer type with the name `TEXT_FUNCTION`, which takes no parameter and returns `char*`.

After the assignment of `textfunction` by the address of the function `getName()`, it could be called as:

```
char* sth = textfunction();
```

which has the same effect with:

```
char* sth = getName();
```